# Limit the size of wxListCtrl in wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I want to limit the size of a list control box. Let us take the following code:

```
import wx

class Students(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(380, 230))

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'name')
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'age')        

        hbox.Add(self.list, 1,wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App()
Students(None, -1, 'studs')
app.MainLoop()
```

If I make the horizontal box sizer's proportion=0, like this:

```
hbox.Add(self.list, 0,wx.EXPAND)
```

then there is a different problem. The problem with proportion=1 is that after 'Age' column, there is a lot of empty space the list control box is eating up for the third column which doesn't exist.
The problem with proportion=0 is that it is too short in width. 
I want to display the list control box with 'Name' and 'Age' columns only and save the rest of the space. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the width of your list control manually and then set the proportion to 0.

The width of columns can be set manually:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT, size=(200, -1))
        column_size = self.list.GetSize()[0] / 2 - 2
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Age')   
        self.list.SetColumnWidth(0, column_size)
        self.list.SetColumnWidth(1, column_size)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.list, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.SetSize((600, 400))       
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Or the ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin may be used:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix

class TestListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.GREEN)

        self.list = TestListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT, size=(200, -1))
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, 'Name')
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, 'Age')   

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.list, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.panel, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.SetSize((600, 400))       
        self.Show()

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use wx.EXPAND if you don't want the control to resize. You could also put a spacer into the horizontal sizer right after the list control and make it expand instead. Then the spacer will take up all the available space.